# how to calculate average dictionary in one function

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
data1 = {'data2' : [70, 70, 70, 100, 100, 100, 120, 120, 150, 150],
         'data3' : [333, 70, 11, 100, 100, 100, 133, 120, 150, 13]}
```

i have first code

```
def function_average(data):
    total = {}
    for k, v in data.items():
        total[k] = sum(v) / float(len(v))
    return total
print(function_average(data1))
```

output

```
{'data2': 105.0, 'data3': 113.0}
```

and second code :

```
def function_average(data):
    total = 0
    for item in data:
        total += item
    avg = total/len(data)
    return avg

def cal_average(data):
    for key in data.keys():
        print ("dictionary",key)
        print (function_average(data[key]))
cal_average(data1)
```

output

```
dictionary data2
105.0
dictionary data3
113.0
```

I want to make one code, but the output is like in the second code.Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
data1 = {'data2' : [70, 70, 70, 100, 100, 100, 120, 120, 150, 150],
         'data3' : [333, 70, 11, 100, 100, 100, 133, 120, 150, 13]}
averages = [(k, sum(v)/len(v)) for k, v in data1.items()]
for k, v in averages:
    print("dictionary", k, f"\n{v}")
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, sir. Sorry sir, can you explain the code line by line? currently i am just learning pyhton and it doesn't understand for me. I can't speak english too well, but I can little by little

Comment: Sure. For this line `[(k, sum(v)/len(v)) for k, v in data1.items()]`, you iterate in the dict's items (k -> key, v -> value = list), and using list-comprehension, you store a tuple containing the key and sum of list/len of list that is average from the dictionary. After that, you just print the `key` first, followed by `f"\n{v}"`, which is an f-string (read up on it) consisting of a newline and the average.

Comment: thanks sir, Wish you always well and success